# Windows 10 - Xbox App doesn't start

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, xbox-one

I've done an upgrade from Windows 7 and everything went smooth, but the Xbox app doesn't start. When I click on the icon, nothing pops up, not even a black window. It's like I was clicking in an empty space in the desktop.

Since then, I've done the following:

```
Remove-AppXPackage for the Xbox App
Clean Store cache using WSReset.exe
Install again from Store
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register XboxAppPath\AppXManifest.xml"
```

No luck.

The file explorer shows two folders related to the app:

```
Microsoft.XboxApp_7.7.29027.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe (50.2 MB)
Microsoft.XboxApp_2015.729.509.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe (23.2 KB)
```

When I try to uninstall it from the Control Panel, there's an entry which seems suspicious:

[image]

Has anybody gone through this and is able to help me?

Comment: Anything suspicious in the Windows event log?  What about MSInstaller setup log?

Comment: The MSInstaller setup log shows nothing, and I don't seem to see anything in the event log either. But I'm guessing that doing a "fresh" reinstall of the app should solve it, right?

Comment: If there's some kind of conflict with the app and your operating environment that's causing a silent crash, it may have been caught by the Windows event log, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem like this, seems like some sort of profile problem since you'll see the app correctly when logged in on another profile. Here's what I did:

1. Backup files, you'll be deleting the user profile.
2. Created local profile with system admin rights.
3. Restarted Computer.
4. Logged in with local system admin profile.
5. Deleted the user that has the Xbox problem.
6. Created user profile again.

Comment: You were right, I tried with my other profile and it just works!! Which files should I backup? I'll delete my profile and create another with admin rights.